# React Native Expo App - How to export more than one component in the same page

Tags: react-native, expo

I have setup basic navigation in my app and now wish to add a drawer menu as well. I have implemented things required so far for the drawer to work but it won't work with my navigation I can only have one or the other.

Here is some of my code in my route.js

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator
(
 {
   Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
   Users: { screen: UserScreen }
 },
 {
   initialRouteName: "Home"
 }
)

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator
(
 {
   Login: LoginScreen,
   Register: RegisterScreen
 }
)

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator
(
 {
   HomeScreen,
   ProfileScreen,
   SettingsScreen
 }
) 

export default createAppContainer(
createSwitchNavigator(
{
  Loading: LoadingScreen,
  App: AppStack,
  Auth: AuthStack,
  Drawer: DrawerNavigator
},
{
  initialRouteName: "Loading"
}
)
)
```

I tried exporting both components separately but I read somewhere you can only have one default export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved problem by adding DrawerNavigator to my AppStack

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, you can only have one default export. You can have multiple named exports or a single default export and multiple named exports.

If you have:

```
const sayHello = () => {};
const sayGoodbye = () => {};
```

Default export and Named export

```
export default sayHello;
export { sayGoodbye }

import sayHello, { sayGoodbye } from 'your-path';
```

Multiple Named exports

```
export { sayHello, sayGoodbye }

import { sayHello, sayGoodbye } from 'your-path';
```

Comment: What if both exports need to share the same identifier, for example, createAppContainer needs to be used with createSwitchNavigator and DrawerNavigator ?